# Access the table cell , below a given cell in a html table

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following table:

```
  ------------------------------------------
 |   catgy 1      |catgy 2 |    catgy 3    |
 |------|---------|--------|----------------
 |item1 |item2    | item3  |    item4      |
 |--|---|--|------|---|----|------|---------
 |A |B  |C | D    | E | F  |    G | H      |
 |--|---|--|------|---|----|------|--------|
```

Given the index of a cell in the third (or greater) row, how can I use jQuery to find the headers associated with that cell.

In other words if cell `F` is clicked, how can I return `catgy 2` and `item3`?

Comment: Will you have any colspans in rows below #2?

Comment: no.  fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mjnmcxav/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What we know

We can easily get our clicked cell's index. Let's say we have a click handler:

```
$(document).on("click", "tr:gt(1) td", function(){
```

This will trigger on `td` cells in every `tr` after you second header row. Inside of this function we can get our cell index using:

```
var cellIndex = $(this).index();
```

## What we don't know

We don't know how to find the header values that correspond with our column. The easiest way to find this is by initializing values when we start up. I would set up an array for each of the header rows that has their content for every column index to which they apply. For the first row it would look like:

```
var primaryHeader = [];
$("tr:eq(0)").children().each(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < $(this).attr("colspan"); i++)
    {
        primaryHeader.push($(this).text());
    }
})
```

The output will be `["catgy 1", "catgy 1", "catgy 1", "catgy 1", "catgy 2", "catgy 2", "catgy 3", "catgy 3"]`.

## Putting it together

Now we can easily associate a header with a certain column index:

```
var header = primaryHeader[ $(this).index() ];
```

**See it working below**

```js
var primaryHeader = [],
    secondaryHeader = [];
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("tr:eq(0)").children().each(function(){
        for (var i = 0; i < $(this).attr("colspan"); i++)
        {
            primaryHeader.push($(this).text());
        }
    })
    console.log(primaryHeader);
    
    $("tr:eq(1)").children().each(function(){
        for (var i = 0; i < $(this).attr("colspan"); i++)
        {
            secondaryHeader.push($(this).text());
        }
    })
    console.log(secondaryHeader);
})

$(document).on("click", "tr:gt(1) td", function(){
    alert("primary header:" + primaryHeader[$(this).index()])
    alert("secondary header:" + secondaryHeader[$(this).index()])
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="sample">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">catgy 1</td>
         <td colspan="2">catgy 2</td>
         <td colspan="2">catgy 3</td>
         
    </tr>  
     <tr>
          <td colspan="2"> item1</td>
          <td colspan="2">item2</td>
          <td colspan="2">item3</td>
         <td colspan="2">item4</td>
     </tr>  
     <tr>
          
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
         <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
     </tr>  
    
</table>
```